# Equivalence of gamma and inverse gamma:Does choosing a prior lead to possibly different evaluations?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

Suppose we had an expressions that was proportional to

$$\frac{1}{\sigma^{3}}\exp(\frac{-\beta}{\sigma^{2}})$$

My question is, can you choose different possible parametrization for a prior distribution?

you could choose a prior,
 $$\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}} \sim Gamma(1/2,\beta)$$

Or you could choose

$$\sigma^{2} \sim Inverse-Gamma(\frac{5}{2},\beta)$$

which correspond to different kernels..

It seems we could take either, but the kernel would then be different leading to differences in integration and such.

So what is it I am missing here? Could you really just choose either one even though they lead to different inferences( I suppose because $1/x^{2}$ is not invariant?

Comment: Forgot Jacobian.

Comment: Thanks but that still wouldn't allow us to know which form to choose for a prior in the example I gave would it? Or is that just a result that choosing a different form of prior that may not be invariant can lead to different results in integration and such

Comment: If you want the inference to correspond, you have to have your priors correspond. Jeffreys priors do this, for example

Comment: Got it, thanks. So if not specified, either interpretation could be seen as valid, even if leading to different conclusions?

Comment: In the same sense that inference based on two distinct priors are both valid, even if leading to different conclusions.

Comment: In the small example I gave, it seems to be the case we could choose diffirent priors.. but it seems to incorrectly contradict the basic result that if X is Gamma(a,b), then (1/X) is inv gamma (a,b)

Comment: @Quality the point is that you are not doing the change of variable correctly, I think.

Comment: @guy  ... Thank you! I see the issue now.. I was thinking you simply fit , and you are right about the Jacobian, the issue of choosing possible different prior is just a separate thing ( I think..it would depend which we choose first)

Comment: That is , I believe the part about me not understanding the 1/x is resolved, as long as what I said makes sense about being able to initially choose possible different prior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is meaningless in my opinion because it is too vague: the "expression" stems out of nowhere (is it a probability density? a likelihood? as a function of $\sigma$?  $\sigma^2$? $\sigma^{-2}$?) and in particular it does not specify the [dominating measure](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2018/11/16/x-entropy/). Is it the Lebesgue measure? the left invariant Haar measure? the right invariant Haar measure? Another measure?

Comment: I should add context. The expression arises when attempting to compute an integral of the form of the top expression.

Comment: (it results from a posterior likelihood of normals with a prior of the form $\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}$